# 401 IIS Error for SearchAdmin.asmx

Tags: 2007, search, error, web-services, 401

I have a three server SharePoint 2007 MOSS environment where my IIS logs continue to get pounded with 401.1 and 401.2.   These logs are filling up so much that they consume my HDD.  I can tell from the IP that these errors are from POST requests from one of my front end web server.  Here is the sequence of logs that repeat forever.  (The xxx IP's are all the same)

```
2011-02-10 23:25:42 W3SVC951338967 xxx.xx.xxx.xx POST /SharedServices1/Search/SearchAdmin.asmx - 56738 MyDomain\SQLSAServiceAccount xxx.xx.xxx.xx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.42) 200 0 0
2011-02-10 23:25:42 W3SVC951338967 xxx.xx.xxx.xx POST /SharedServices1/Search/SearchAdmin.asmx - 56738 - xxx.xx.xxx.xx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.42) 401 2 2148074254
2011-02-10 23:25:42 W3SVC951338967 xxx.xx.xxx.xx POST /SharedServices1/Search/SearchAdmin.asmx - 56738 - xxx.xx.xxx.xx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.42) 401 1 0
```

I really need some help trying to understand the source of this.

Thanks for your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the resolution on my [blog](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.com/2011/07/sharepoint-http-error-4011-unauthorized.html)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP error 401.1 means access denied due to invalid credentials. The 401.2 error is access denied due to server configuration. So basically these errors are authentication failures. Without more information about your setup it is difficult to say much more. In particular, it depends whether you have Kerberos enabled or not, and how you address the servers (loopback check issue).